# Mutex unlock failure when trying to acquire a QSemaphore

Tags: multithreading, qt, synchronization, qthread

I have an application with 2 QThreads which behave like it in the pseudocode below (the semaphores are of type QSemaphore):

```
Thread1 {
    print("about to wait on semaphore 1");
    sem1.acquire(1);
    print("finished waiting on semaphore 1");
    sem2.release(1);
}

Thread2 {
    print("signaling semaphore 1");
    sem1.release(1);
    print("about to wait on semaphore 2");
    sem2.acquire(1);
}
```

The issue is that the first thread does NOT wake up when the first semaphore is signalled, i.e. the application produces the following output:

```
about to wait on semaphore 1
signaling semaphore 1
about to wait on semaphore 2
```

And that's it. The first thread no longer wakes up.

Now I change the first thread to do the following:

```
Thread1 {
    print("about to wait on semaphore 1");
    while (!sem1.tryAcquire(1, 200));
    print("finished waiting on semaphore 1");
    sem2.release(1);
}
```

In this case the first thread sleeps for at most 200ms before it tries to acquire the semaphore again. Now I get the following error:

```
QWaitCondition::wait(): mutex unlock failure: Invalid argument
```

No other mutexes or other synchronisation primitives are used by the application. What could be the issue?

**Update**:

I've removed the Semaphores and replaced each with a QWaitCondition and a QMutex and now it works just fine. I didn't make any other changes and I still don't know why the version with semaphores was incorrect. They were both initialised to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you do something wrong somewhere else (e.g., semaphore initialization code).

---

The following example compiles and runs (gcc).

**threads.h:**

```
#pragma once

#include <QThread>

class Thread1 : public QThread
{
protected:
    virtual void run();
};

class Thread2 : public QThread
{
protected:
    virtual void run();
};
```

**threads.cpp:**

```
#include "threads.h"

#include <QSemaphore>
#include <iostream>

namespace
{
QSemaphore sem1, sem2;
}

void Thread1::run()
{
    std::cout << "about to wait on semaphore 1\n";
    sem1.acquire(1);
    //while (!sem1.tryAcquire(1, 200));     //works too
    std::cout << "finished waiting on semaphore 1\n";
    sem2.release(1);
}

void Thread2::run()
{
    std::cout << "signaling semaphore 1\n";
    sem1.release(1);
    std::cout << "about to wait on semaphore 2\n";
    sem2.acquire(1);
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "threads.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Thread1 t1;
    Thread2 t2;
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t1.wait();
    t2.wait();
    std::cout << "Success\n";
}
```

**possible output:**

```
signaling semaphore 1
about to wait on semaphore 2
about to wait on semaphore 1
finished waiting on semaphore 1
Success
```

Comment: Hint: your example doesn't need to use `<iostream>` nor multiple files. Use `qDebug() << "Success";` and use only a single `#include <QtCore>` within `main.cpp`.

Comment: @Kuba Ober threads.h is there because of moc, threads.cpp is there for localizing semaphores in a separate translation unit. And I prefer language's standard library over Qt's implementation (matter of taste) :-)

Comment: I've removed the Semaphores and replaced each with a QWaitCondition and a QMutex and now it works just fine. I didn't make any other changes and I still don't know why the version with semaphores was incorrect. They were both initialised to 0.

Comment: These two `QThread`-derived classes don't need the `Q_OBJECT` macro. But if they did, you could just add `#include "main.moc"` at the end of the `main.cpp`.

Comment: Right, not in this case, fixed it.  Thanks @KubaOber